# where do the uploaded files using multipart forms gets saved?

Tags: html, cgi, server-side

I wanted to know that where will the files uploaded by clients gets saved,if i am using multipart forms and also will these files be saved permanently and if 2 or more users are trying to upload files at the same time so will both of there files be saved or overwrite??

My cgi script is a .py script

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think uploaded files get saved "automagically". Your script needs to process the request and save them.

Answer (score 0):

These files will be saved in a temporary directory, you will need to save them manually.

You can control the files using PERL, something like this:

```
require "cgi-lib.pl";
$uploadDirectory = "YOUR_DIRECTORY";
open (OUTPUT_FILE, ">$upload_dir\/$in{'file'}") || & Die("Could not open file: $!");
undef $Buffer;
while (read($in{'file'},$Buffer,1024)) {
     print OUTPUT_FILE $Buffer;
}
close(OUTPUT_FILE);
```

To handle multiple uploads you can make sure you give them separate names (eg. including the user_id, or random).

Comment: kkz,,,I save them manually but if 2 or more users are trying to upload their files at the same time with same name let say hello.html so will these files be saved as differnt or will they be overwritten

Comment: Again, this is a manual process. You can verify a file with the same name exist and save with a different name eg Name_1, Name_2 and so on. Best practice would be to save the file as a random encrypt and store the text in a database, if you use the name provided in the front you are exposing to path traversal attacks (see the owasp.com website for more details about webapps security).

Comment: And i have no knowledge of db or mysql so is this possible that 2 users files of same names get saved differnetly??

Comment: yes, you check if the filename exists and if it doesn't you add a suffix to it. best practice would be not to save a file with the provided name.